# Newly added element can't traverse up through its ancestors in the DOM tree using jQuery API closest(), returning "undefined"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The idea of the following codes is to realize the function of "click to edit".

1. Edit. When a user clicks the "edit" button, an "editing component"(an input bar and two buttons for canceling or confirming) will replace the original text, and the "edit" button is disabled.
2. Cancel. When a user clicks the "cancel" button, the original text will replace the editing component, and the "edit" button is enabled.
3. Confirm. When a user clicks the "submit" button, the new text will replace the editing component, and the "edit" button is enabled.

The operation is based on 5 classes: `.rootClickEdit`, `textEdit`, `.buttonEdit`, `.buttonOk` and `.buttonCancel`.

There are two kinds of html codes that is controlled by js codes.

html1:

```
<div class="row rootClickEdit">
  <div class="col-xs-2 stigmod-attri-cont-left">name</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 stigmod-attri-cont-middle textEdit">CourseActivity</div>
  <div class="col-xs-4 stigmod-attri-cont-right">
    <div class="stigmod-hovershow-cont">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit buttonEdit"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

html2:

```
<div class="row rootClickEdit">
  <div class="col-xs-8" id="stigmod-classname">
    <span class="stigmod-keepinline">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-large" id="stigmod-classname-icon"></span>
      <span id="stigmod-classname-title">CLASS</span>
      <span> |&nbsp;</span>
    </span>
    <span class="textEdit">CourseActivity</span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <div class="btn-group pull-right">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" data-original-title="Add a new attribute"></span>
      </button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default buttonEdit">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" data-original-title="Edit class name"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" data-original-title="Configurations"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu">
          <li><a href="#">Delete this class</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
  function submitEdit(event) {
    var newText = $(this).parent().prev().val();  // get palceholder
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().html(newText);  // use the new text to replace the editing component
    // enable editing function
    var buttonDisable = $(this).closest('.rootClickEdit').find('.buttonEdit');
    var tagName = buttonDisable[0].tagName;
    if ('BUTTON' === tagName) {
      buttonDisable.removeClass('disabled');
    } else if ('SPAN' === tagName) {
      buttonDisable.addClass('glyphicon-edit');
    }
    event.preventDefault();
  }
  function cancelEdit(event) {
    var originalText = $(this).parent().prev().attr('placeholder');  // get palceholder
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().html(originalText);  // use the original text to replace the editing component
    // enable editing function
    var buttonDisable = $(this).closest('.rootClickEdit').find('.buttonEdit');
    var tagName = buttonDisable[0].tagName;
    if ('BUTTON' === tagName) {
      buttonDisable.removeClass('disabled');
    } else if ('SPAN' === tagName) {
      buttonDisable.addClass('glyphicon-edit');
    }
    event.preventDefault();  
  }
  function editElem(event) {
    var originalTextElem = $(this).closest('.rootClickEdit').find('.textEdit');
    var originalText = originalTextElem.text();
    var editComponent = 
      '<span class="input-group input-group-xs">' +
        '<input type="text" class="form-control" value="' + originalText + '" placeholder="' + originalText + '">' +
        '<span class="input-group-btn">' +
          '<button class="btn btn-default buttonOk" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span></button>' +
          '<button class="btn btn-default buttonCancel" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></button>' +
        '</span>' +
      '</span>';
    var buttonDisable = $(this);
    alert($(this)[0].tagName + '\n' + $(this).parents().attr('class'));
    var tagName = buttonDisable[0].tagName;
    if ('BUTTON' === tagName) {
      buttonDisable.addClass('disabled');
    } else if ('SPAN' === tagName) {
      buttonDisable.removeClass('glyphicon-edit');
    }
    originalTextElem.html(editComponent);  // use the editing component to replace the original text，and put the original text into placeholder
    event.preventDefault();
  }
  $('.rootClickEdit').on('click', '.buttonEdit', editElem); // click to edit
  $('.rootClickEdit').on('click', '.buttonOk', submitEdit); // submit the editing
  $('.rootClickEdit').on('click', '.buttonCancel', cancelEdit); // cancel the editing
});
```

**The problem is that `$(this).closest('.rootClickEdit')` in function `cancelEdit()` returns `undefined` rather than the `<div class="row rootClickEdit">` element. Why? And how to fix it?**

BTW, the way of realizing "click to edit" is totally my intuition. Is there any better way to do it? Thanks!

Comment: That is because you attached the cancelEdit function to the onClick listener of a `.rootClickEdit` element. So `$(this)` would already give you the `<div class="row rootClickEdit"></div>` element

Comment: @Ronald01990 jQuery API `on()` with three parameters does not work the way as you said. In the callback function `editElem()` of `$('.rootClickEdit').on('click', '.buttonEdit', editElem);`, the value of `$(this)` is the `.buttonEdit` element rather than `.rootClickEdit`. I checked this by `alert($(this).attr('class'));` in `editElem()`. So does the other two listeners.

Comment: Oh yeah, that's right, my bad. I found your error. Will post an answer in a minute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the cancel button is removed in the cancelEdit() function before you try to find the edit button. Moving that line above where you replace the html will do it:

```
function cancelEdit(event) {
    var buttonDisable = $(this).closest('.rootClickEdit').find('.buttonEdit');
    var originalText = $(this).parent().prev().attr('placeholder');  // get palceholder
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().html(originalText);  // use the original text to replace the editing component
    // enable editing function
    var tagName = buttonDisable[0].tagName;
    if ('BUTTON' === tagName) {
      buttonDisable.removeClass('disabled');
    } else if ('SPAN' === tagName) {
      buttonDisable.addClass('glyphicon-edit');
    }
    event.preventDefault();  
}
```

Comment: You solved my problem. I'm a newbie with js. Even when the cancel button is removed after `$(this).parent().parent().parent().html(newText);`, the removed part of DOM tree still exists in function `cancelEdit()`, which legislates traversal inside the removed part such as `$(this).closest('.input-group')`. That blinded me. Thank you~